# How to add strings together after being in an if statement

Tags: java

I have created an if statement that creates a variable of a string if a certain key is pressed. I want to then at the end add all the created variables so the can be outputted as it is a ticketing program. I am also want help as how I can make the character 'X' stop the while loop all I essentially want to do is allow the user to select a section(s) and then print out the section(s) they chose as well as there total. Please help.

```
/* Name:
 * Date:
 * Course:
 * Description:
 */

import hsa.Console;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.imageio.*;
import java.io.*;

public class raps
{
  static Console c;
  static Image image;
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {

    c = new Console();
    image = null;

    //Copy and paste this below every time you want to put in a new picture

    {
      String a1;
      String b1;
      String z1;
      String d1;
      String e1;
     String f1;


      double a = 0.0;
      double b = 0.0;
      double z = 0.0;
      double d = 0.00;
      double e = 0.0;
      double f = 0.0;



      ticket first = new ticket();
      first.selection = 'A';
      first.ticketType = "Courtside Prime";
      first.price = 360.00;

      ticket second = new ticket();
      second.selection = 'B';
      second.ticketType = "Baseline Prime";
      second.price = 106.50;

      ticket third = new ticket();
      third.selection = 'C';
      third.ticketType = "Box Seat";
      third.price = 97.00;

      ticket fourth = new ticket();
      fourth.selection = 'D';
      fourth.ticketType = "Lower Bowl";
      fourth.price = 94.50;

      ticket fifth = new ticket();
      fifth.selection = 'E';
      fifth.ticketType = "Upper Bowl";
      fifth.price = 91.00;

      ticket sixth = new ticket();
      sixth.selection = 'F';
      sixth.ticketType = "Drake Zone";
      sixth.price = 50.00;



      c.println(" A | Courtside Prime | $360.00 ");
       c.println(" B | Baseline Prime  | $106.50 ");
       c.println(" C |     Box Seat    | $97.00 ");
       c.println(" D |    Lower Bowl   | $94.50 ");
       c.println(" E |    Upper Bowl   | $91.00 ");
       c.println(" F |    Drake Zone   | $50.00 ");



       char choice;
       choice = c.readChar();
       while(choice != 'X') {
       c.println("Enter the letter of the seat section you would like to select");
       choice = c.readChar();
       if (choice == 'A');{
        a = first.price;
        a1 = first.ticketType;
       }
       if (choice == 'B');{
        b = second.price;
        b1 = second.ticketType;
       }
        if (choice == 'C');{
        z = third.price;
        z1 = third.ticketType;
       }
          if (choice == 'D');{
        d = fourth.price;
        d1 = fourth.ticketType;
       }
               if (choice == 'E');{
        e = fifth.price;
        e1 = fifth.ticketType;
       }
         if (choice == 'F');{
        f = sixth.price;
        f1 = sixth.ticketType;
       }

       }

       double total = (a + b + z + d + e + f);
       String totalText = (a1 + b1 + z1 + d1 e1 +f1);

    }





  }
}
class ticket{
  char selection;          //The Letter of Selection The User will choose ex. A, B, C etc.
  String ticketType;      //The type of ticket the user will choose ex. Courtside Prime, Baseline Prime etc.
  double price;          //The price of each ticket

}
```

It will eventually print out the culmitive total and the tickets sections which they selected after they hit x which I want to end the while loop but dont know how

Comment: You're creating a String value in the code that kind of looks like what you're asking us to help you with, totalText, but don't appear to be doing anything with it -- why? If you're wanting to print it, then do so using `println`.

Comment: `String totalText = (a1 + b1 + z1 + d1 e1 +f1);` there is a missing `+` between `d1` and `e1`

Comment: Maybe you should touch bases with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58560823/the-ticket-class-not-being-recognized

Answer (score 0):

This is a big part of the issue.  The semi-colon after the if makes it an empty conditional block.  The remain code is always executed.  And this is just an example, each if statement has this issue.

```
   if (choice == 'A');{
    a = first.price;
    a1 = first.ticketType;
   }
```

Should be like this instead

```
   if (choice == 'A') {
       a = first.price;
       a1 = first.ticketType;
   }
```

You probably don't want the first line that asks the user for input.

```
    char choice;
    // choice = c.readChar();
    while(choice != 'X') {
        c.println("Enter the letter of the seat section you would like to select");
        choice = c.readChar();
```